# How we can copy any file within Azure Data Lake Store folders

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

We already have `Move-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem`which will move files between folders inside Azure datalake. What I am seeking is to copy files within the datalake without effecting the original file.

The possibilities that I know are-

1. using `USQL` to `EXTRACT` data from sourcefile and then `OUTPUT` to the destinationfile - but I am trying to copy all sort of files (.gz,.txt,.info,.exe,.msi) and I am not sure if `USQL` can help me with .gz or .exe or .msi files
2. using `Data Factory` to copy data from/to `Data Lake store`

So, my ask here is do we have anything else at our disposal with which we can perform a copy of files within Azure Data Lake Store?

Comment: One other approach to consider is, maybe don't copy your files so much?  You could land your data in your lake "raw" or staging area, then  any additional versions of that file should be refinements, aggregates, cleansed, augmented or processed in some way, not straight duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have couple of other options,

1. run distcp on an HDI cluster - Similar to instructions provided here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-wasb-distcp
2. use adlcopy if you are copying limited amount of data (saying 10-100's of GB) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob

Does this suffice please? Or do you want something natively supported by Azure Data Lake Store via its REST APIs?

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager, Azure Data Lake.

Comment: Thanks @Sachin - let me just go through the articles and explore the possibilities. I might bug you back if I need more information on this, if that's ok with you :)